# ID3v2, wrong APIC frame size calculation

Tags: c++, byte, mp3, id3, id3v2

The data size of each ID3v2 frame is stored in **4**, **5**, **6** and **7** bytes of the frame header block (according to documentation):

[image]

I am reading frame sizes from this mp3 file:
[image]

To convert to integer the frame data size, I use the following code:

```
int frame_data_sz = b4 << 21 | b5 << 14 | b6 << 7 | b7;
```

For example, for most frames, this code correctly calculates the frame size:

**TALB** -> 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 -> 2 bytes - correct!

**TIT2** -> 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 -> 2 bytes - correct!

**TPE1** -> 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 -> 2 bytes - correct!

**TCON** -> 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 -> 2 bytes - correct!

**TCOM** -> 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 -> 2 bytes - correct!

**TRCK** -> 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x03 -> 3 bytes - correct!

**TLEN** -> 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x06 -> 6 bytes - correct!

**COMM** -> 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x06 -> 6 bytes - correct!

**APIC** -> 0x00 0x01 0x0F 0x5D -> 18397 bytes - **INCORRECT!**

For "APIC" frame my code calculates wrong frame size value because actual data size value is **71517** bytes.

**How correctly convert the frame size to an integer value?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 4th byte of the ID3v2 header tells us its version:

- `$02` was [version 2.2.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20200328055811/http://id3.org/id3v2-00),
- `$03` is [version 2.3.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20200413172744/https://id3.org/id3v2.3.0) = your file,
- `$04` would be [version 2.4.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20200413173028/https://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-structure) = how you treat the file reading the frames.

While the header size is stored the same for all 3 versions, the frame sizes are all stored differently - your way of reading would only be valid for version 2.4.0:

| bytes \ version | 2.2.0 | 2.3.0 | 2.4.0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| header size | 4 * `%0xxxxxxx` = 28 bit | 4 * `%0xxxxxxx` = 28 bit | 4 * `%0xxxxxxx` = 28 bit |
| frame size | `$xx xx xx` = 24 bit | `$xx xx xx xx` = 32 bit | 4 * `%0xxxxxxx` = 28 bit |

But there are more inconsistencies, hinting at misunderstanding the tag format from whichever software wrote it:

- All the text frames with a size of 2 are effectively empty. Why would a software even store empty frames, instead of omitting them?
- All the text frames, including the comment, have an unneeded terminating `$00` in it, further inflating the size of the tag for no purpose.
- The comment frame only carries the information that it is in the language `rus`, but since both description and text are empty, this is a waste of space (and sense), too.
- The `APIC` size is `$00 01 0f 5d`, which is in decimal actually 69,469 (67.84 KiB). This is off by your expectation of 2048 bytes.